# Automatic Normalization of VARCHAR columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, normalization

Imagine you have many tables which have a `VARCHAR(50)` column called `Country`, there is a small number of different country names which repeat millions of times, the wise thing to do here is to create a table called `dbo.Country(CountryID, CountryName)` and have all the tables hold `CountryID` with a foreign key reference.

Problem is we have to JOIN all our queries with `dbo.Country` every time we want do something with that column.

But all the joins seem to follow the same pattern, so my question is, can SQL Server do it automatically? For example I would specify a column called `CountryName` in some table which looks like a `VARCHAR` but is actually stored as a `CountryID` with foreign key, and SQL Server could implicitly add the JOIN whenever necessary.

Is there such a feature in SQL Server or any other SQL database?

Comment: _"Problem is we have to JOIN all our queries with dbo.Country every time we want do something with that column."_ This a misconception. You have to join every time you want to _display_ the country name. For any other purpose there's no need to join because your country ID (please use ISO 3116-1 and save yourself a lot of pain) represents that country as if the name were in the database; that's the definition of the relation.

Comment: @Ben I didn't elaborate so as not to make the question too long, the situation I have is that I'm always connecting this data to data imported from other sources and sometimes I need to manipulate the string values a little bit, so that's when I need to do the joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this "automatically".  However, you do have a couple of options.

One is to create a view on top of the table that automatically does the join:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, c.CountryName
    from table t join
         country c
         on t.countryId = c.countryId;
```

Alternatively, you could make `Country` an enumerated type.  That would allow it to be accessed as a string but stored as an integer.